# What am I doing wrong here? Simplifying quotient of $2/x$ and $4/(x+4)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find $f/g$ and its domain

$$f(x)=\frac { 2 }{ x } ,\quad g(x)=\frac { 4 }{ x+4 } $$

So I did: $$\frac { \frac { 2 }{ x }  }{ \frac { 4 }{ x+4 }  } $$

Which can also be written as:

$$f/g = \frac { 2 /x}{ 4/(x+4) }  $$

Which comes out to:

$$f/g  = \frac { 2x+8 }{ 4x } = \frac{x+4}{2x} $$

The answer key says that is the wrong answer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not remove the factor 2, common to top and bottom. Also the question asked for the domain as well.

Comment: $2$ in the numerator divides $4$ in the denominator, so it is $\frac{x+4}{2x}$

Comment: @Vikram I don't understand

Comment: $\frac{2}{x} \times \frac {x+4}{4}=\frac{2\times (x+4)}{x \times 2 \times 2}$

Comment: @Vikram So I was right? I just had to factor it?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer,yes, factor out $2$ in the last expression that you have written and then cancel it.

Comment: $f(x)$ is not defined for $x=0$, $g(x)$is not defined for $x=-4$ and $f/g$ is not defined for $x=0$, combin all the constraints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$

Your answer is correct but it lacks simplification:

$$\frac{2x+8}{4x}=\frac{\cancel2(x+4)}{\cancel2\times 2x}=\frac{x+4}{2x}$$

Answer (score 4):

$$ f(x)=\frac{2}{x};\quad g(x)=\frac{4}{x+4}$$
$$(f/g)(x)=\frac{2}{x}\times\frac{x+4}{4}=\frac{x+4}{2x}$$
$$D(f/g)=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0,-4\}$$

Comment: The answer key saids $x$ cannot be $-4$ as well

Comment: That's because at $x=-4$ g is not defined.